# String indexing vs. dynamic array indexing in Delphi

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, why are AnsiStrings indexed from one and dynamic arrays indexed from zero?  Is this a historical accident, to make AnsiStrings work more like ShortStrings, or is there some deeper logic at work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the contributing factors that led to "Pascal" strings being 1 indexed instead of 0 indexed was that the length of the string was stored in the zeroth byte. Yes, that could have been hidden from the programmer's view by having the compiler internally add a constant offset to the string index expression (as was done in Delphi's long strings later) but in the beginning things were much simpler. Allocate a block of memory, store the length in byte zero, index the char data from byte 1. End of story.

As I recall UCSD Pascal was using this length-in-zero-byte convention long before Turbo Pascal came along.

As for why dynamic arrays are zero based, I don't recall any specific reason but I would guess it reflects the dynamic array's kinship to dynamically allocating a buffer and indexing off the buffer pointer. The array types that you would use to create array pointer types were zero based arrays. The first byte is found at buffer pointer + 0 offset. This is the C rationalization for zero based everything. There was no compelling reason to carry string's 1 based indexing pattern over to compiler managed arrays when string's 1 based indexing was already (and had always been) the exception rather than the norm.

It may well be that because the string type was the first array-like data type that everyone first encountered and possibly the most used data type across the board, there may be a perception of a bias towards 1 based indexing in the language. However, if you look closely I think you'll find arrays in Pascal (distinct from string) have never been inherently 1 based, especially when dynamically allocated.

Comment: 0-based indexing has measurable performance benefits over 1-based. I'm very happy that dyn arrays went that way.

Comment: I selected this answer because it's a more focused answer to my actual question, but @DavidHeffernan's answer has some other useful information that I'm very happy to have.

Comment: Looking into it further, it sounds like the only performance benefit is not needing to decrement the index when doing the pointer arithmetic to access elements of the array.

Comment: The performance benefit that Jason describes. It's not huge, but it is sometimes measurable.

Comment: If the size of the array element is a power of two, the compiler can usually fold the index base adjustment into an x86 indexed memory load instruction (ModR/M byte). No performance difference at all.

Comment: And even without the mod R/M byte encoding trick, in a "clean" for loop where the loop index variable is used to index into the array, the compiler will usually be able to perform loop induction (modify the range of the for loop index variable to match the range of the array), again eliminating the index base adjustment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "but it is sometimes measurable" That's a little different from your first statement. ;>  If you're going to play the perf card, I'm going to call you on it. :P

Comment: Hmm, interesting stuff. Dissasembler writes code like this: `mov ebx,[esp+ebx*4-$04]` but that's just a single opcode. So no matter that the op looks complex, the chip handles it. I never knew this and had been labouring under a false impression. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: No problem. It's why they keep us old farts around. ;>

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the Delphi string tradition of 1-based strings is quite simple. The tradition comes from the implementation of old style Turbo Pascal strings. That data type stored the length of the string in the first byte of the variable, index 0. The string data began in the next byte, index 1.

You can still use that data type today. It's now called ShortString. As is immediately obvious from it's implementation, there is a 255 character limit. This limit led to the introduction of huge strings, if I recall correctly, in Delphi 2. When huge strings were introduced the language designers chose to retain 1-based indexing to make it easier for developers to switch from short strings to huge strings.

I guess Turbo Pascal didn't invent the idea of using element 0 for length. It's just that I'm too young to remember what came before then!

Dynamic arrays weren't bound by the past in the same way and had a free choice. I don't know why zero based was chosen. Perhaps because it fits more easily with the prevailing fashion on platform on which Delphi existed at that time, namely Windows. That's just a guess though. Danny Thorpe worked on the Delphi compiler at that time, and even he [can't remember the rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132973/string-indexing-vs-dynamic-array-indexing-in-delphi#answer-13135052)!

The Delphi language designers are currently moving towards zero based string indexing for huge strings. The initial steps in this direction can be seen in XE3 in the TStringHelper class which uses 0-based indexing. And also in the ZEROBASEDSTRINGS conditional which allows you to opt in to 0-based indexing. Expect the next generation Delphi compiler to use 0-based indexing only. The times they are changin'.

Answer (score 0):

Historical accident.

Pascal strings and arrays traditionally start at 1.

C - and perhaps consequently AnsiStrings - start at 0.

I don't know the rationale for "breaking with Pascal tradition" for Dynamic arrays, which also start at zero.  But it makes sense, and I agree with it ...

IMHO...

Comment: there was no tradition. In Pascal there were no Open Arrays nor Dynamic ones, so they could be introduced with any semantics. BTW "C - and perhaps consequently AnsiStrings" is  wrong, AnsiString is just usual string in Delphi 2 - 2007, it starts with [1] too.